# Color mapping large picture

Tags: cocoa

I have a BMP file that is 3k*2k pixels, 24 bits per pixel.  There are about 1500 colors in the picture.  I want to be able to map each specific color to a different specific color.  I'd rather not iterate thru 6 megapixels 1500 times.  What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Depending on what you'd specifically like to do *CoreImage* filters might be the most convenient way to achieve that effect?

Comment: Sorry, which part of "map each specific color to a different specific color" isn't specific enough?  If CI handled paletted images, I'd say I just want to change the color palette, but it doesn't.

Near as I can tell, the only thing close in CI is CIColorCube.  Given the colors in the image, I'd need a cube on the order of 58*58*58=195,112 elements.